# How to specify bundle type in custom block written programmatically?

Tags: 8, blocks

How to specify bundle for the blocks you build programmatically since you need block bundles to entity reference the block?[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to reference the block in a paragraph type...reference is done based on block types...

Comment: Can you try to be a bit more specific. It is very hard to give a good answer when the question is as vague as it is right now. For example: what do you mean be reference? Do you want to create a link to the block? do you want to display the block? do you want to get metadata information about the block? How did you define the block_type (code snippet)?

Comment: P.S. you don't need the block_type for an entity_reference field to the block entity. It is a configuration entity and you only need the id of the block instance.

Comment: I have added a picture in question where it asks for bundles to reference a block. I have a custom form in a block, therefore i wrote it programmatically. I want to display that block in a node using paragraphs module . I couldn't find anywhere how to specify the bundle for the block? This is my annotation for the custom block.

`/**
 * Provides Custom Block.
 *
 * @Block(
 * id = "connected_block",
 * admin_label = @Translation("Connected Block with Form"),
 * category = @Translation("Blocks")
 * )
 */ `